# error: pyspark list append operation inside foreach on dataframe gives empty list outside of loop

Tags: list, dataframe, loops, pyspark, foreach

I am facing the following issue:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()

data = [('James','Smith','M',30),('Anna','Rose','F',41),('Robert','Williams','M',62), ]
columns = ["firstname","lastname","gender","salary"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema = columns)
lst = []

def func2(x):
    lst = lst.append(x.firstname)

df.foreach(func2)
# df.foreach(lambda x: func2(x))

print(len(lst))
```

the `lst` variable here at the end of the loop is always empty. what is the reason for this? any fix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code does not work is because lambda functions in PySpark are executed in different executors, each within its own local Python process and hence global variables are not accessible across executors.

You can use [`accumulators`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.Accumulator.html) to achieve this. However, it comes with a performance penalty and PySpark does not provide a native `List` accumulator.

### Solution using Accumulators

```py
from pyspark.accumulators import AccumulatorParam

class ListParam(AccumulatorParam):
    def zero(self, init_value):
        return init_value
    def addInPlace(self, v1, v2):
        return v1 + v2

lst = spark.sparkContext.accumulator([], ListParam())

def func2(x):
    global lst
    lst += [x.firstname]

df.foreach(func2)

print(lst.value)
```

**Output:**

```
['James', 'Anna', 'Robert']
```

If you are looking to get back all the values for a particular column in PySpark then you can select the particular column, [`collect`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.collect.html?highlight=collect) them as [`Row`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Row.html?highlight=rows) and then fetch the key you are interested in.

> Collecting is an expensive operation and brings all the data to the driver and in the presence of all volume of data, it will cause driver to fail.

```py
[row.firstname for row in df.select("firstname").collect()]
```

Comment: Any way to then convert the lst of type accumulator to actual python list? My need is to pass this lst as a python list to another API.

Comment: `lst.value` gives you the actual Python list.